# redis opsForZSet error

Tags: java, redis

Im using redis to store certain keys and a set of values where I want t remove a specific valuer when the corresponding operations to that particular value is done.

My code segment for removing the particular value is

```
redisOperations.opsForZSet().remove(key, task); and /i'm getting the error

Exception in thread "scheduler-polling" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.core.ZSetOperations.remove(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
```

my key is a String and the task is also a string. I see no reason why it doesn't accept this.

Comment: How about [this](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/480)? Might be your version of `jedis` is conflicting with something, can you add information on which redis driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your exception you are trying to return a Boolean value, while this method returns a Long value according to documentation.

Take a look in the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ZSetOperations.html#remove-K-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to return anything. I do not make use of any return value there.

Comment: Make sure to use a compatible Jedis version. Take a look into the pom.xml of the `spring-data-redis` jar.